# WooCommerce ShortCodes [products ids=","] embeded with [tabbed_section] MisBehaving

Tags: woocommerce

Platform = WP 3.9.1 with WooCommerce 2.1.2

Using ShortCodes to display multiple Tabbed Product Carousels (on HomePage) each with 4 columns and 8 products : need about 6 product carousels/slider.

```
Code : 
[tabbed_section]
[tab title="A"] [products ids="1, 2, 3, 4"] [/tab] [tab title="B"] [products ids="5, 6, 7, 8"][/tab] [tab title="C"] [products ids="9, 10, 11, 12"] [/tab] [tab title="D"][products ids="13, 14, 15, 16"][/tab][tab title="E"][products ids="17, 18, 19, 20"][/tab]
[/tabbed_section]
```

Issue :
In this first block, under each tab, only three products are being displayed in the first row and the fourth product is being pushed to a second row.  The carousel navigation is absent.

```
Code :
[tabbed_section]
[tab title="F"][products ids="21, 22, 23, 24"][/tab]
[/tabbed_section]
```

Issue :
This is the second block.  Same issues as in first block above + After the first tab which is "F", displaying an exact copy of Tabs "B" + "C" + "D" + "E"

The entire code is below :

```
[container]

[brands title="Shop by Brand"]

[custom_featured_products title="DEALS"]

[tabbed_section]
[tab title="A"] [products ids="1, 2, 3, 4"] [/tab] [tab title="B"] [products ids="5,   6, 7, 8"][/tab] [tab title="C"] [products ids="9, 10, 11, 12"] [/tab]
[/tabbed_section] 

[tabbed_section]
[tab title="D"][products ids="13, 14, 15, 16"][/tab][tab title="E"][products ids="17, 18, 19, 20"][/tab][tab title="F"][products ids="21, 22, 23, 24"][/tab]
[/tabbed_section]

[recent_posts title="Latest Deals"]

[/container]
```